# Communicating between front-end and microservices

Tags: server, microservices, devops

So in my uni project the prof said we could try using microservices, so why not try it right? I have one problem thought. I dont have a clue how to communicate from the front-end (client side app) to the backend.

With a monolith its easy. Front-end runs at adress:port xxxx backend runs at adress:port yyyy just call port yyyy everytime you want data.
But how do you do this with microservices without having tons of different addresses in your frontend code?

One Idea i had, was to make a sort off server in the middle that the frontend woud call and that server would check what microservice should be called and then return the result to the frontend from the microservice.

Basically:

1.Frontend calls that server in the middle for products

2.The server in the middle sees that the frontend wants products so it calls the products microservice on its port.

3.Returns the result of the products microservice to the user.

Would this approach work?

Comment: Yes, it would work - that pattern is often called "BFF" (backend for frontend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many ways. Nothing is right or wrong.

If you have Many micro services, say more than 10, `service mesh` is commonly used pattern.where each service may call 1 or more downstream services. In this case, each service needs to know what are the addresses of other services it depends on.

If you want to route through a single service. Well this is gateway pattern. Where all your requests go through one service and it in turn routes to downstream services.

For ex:
192.168.14.2:8080/account
192.168.14.2:8080/something

Based on routes, this gateway service can call `accout-service` or `something-service`
This is not suitable when you add more services over time.
Load on gateway service will increase and it becomes a single point of failure
You can user spring cloud gateway for example. This is exactly like your solution

Hope that answers your question